# Extjs 4 handling external events

Tags: javascript, events, iframe, extjs

I have an Extjs 4 app that is running as an iframe in another web app (written in Javascript). I would like to somehow fire an event **externally** and catch it in the framework.
That is, I would like to emulate

```
 this.application.fireEvent('myevent', myparams);
```

I currently have a workaround. In my external app, I can do things like...

```
var w = document.getElementById('myIFRAME').contentWindow;
if (w) {
    w._myFunctionInExtjs(myParam);
}
```

...which calls a global function declared in my Ext code. It would be a lot cleaner if it's done through the Ext events though, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using my workaround and created ONE global function. All it does it fires off Ext events.

```
//  global function that is used for triggering Ext events 
function _appFireEvent(eventName, objParam) {
    _extApp.fireEvent(eventName, objParam);    
}
```

Now, from my external site, I can call it and tell it which event I want raised:

```
var w = document.getElementById('myIFRAME').contentWindow;
if (w) w._appFireEvent('mycustomevent', myparam);
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this. Using your workaround is the best option I can think of.